# Spring @RolesAllowed: return 403 or 401, but not 500 error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-restcontroller

I want to declare security settings of my Spring `@RestController` by annotating methods instead of specify ANT matchers in Spring security configuration bean.

I wrote something like this (I am using Kotlin and Spring WebFlux):

```
@RestController
open class MyController {
    @GetMapping("/public")
    open suspend fun public() {
        ...
    }


    @GetMapping("/private")
    @RolesAllowed("user")
    open suspend fun public() {
        ...
    }
}
```

I also enabled global method security in my security configuration class:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        prePostEnabled = true,
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true
)
```

I want that the first method can be called by anyone (even by anonymous users) and the second one method can be called only by authenticated user with specified role.

But when I call private method by anonymous user I got 500 server error and stack trace:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:379) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.0.RELEASE.jar:5.3.0.RELEASE]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
```

I want to return more relevant error code such as 401 or 403.

Comment: did you add configuration method of websecurityconfigure adapater in your configuration class?

Comment: I added configuration bean: @Bean open fun securityWebFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain in which enabled any exchange without authentication.